# I need suggestions with this google scripts code

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function insertTwoBlankRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var currentRow = 1;

  // We will loop through each row and insert two new rows below it.
  while (currentRow <= lastRow) {
    // Insert two blank rows below the current row
    sheet.insertRowsAfter(currentRow, 2);

    // Move to the next data row, which is now three rows down due to the inserted rows
    currentRow += 3;

    // Increment the last row by 2, since we've added two new rows
    lastRow += 2;
  }
}
```

What this formula does in google apps scripts is add two new rows after every third. For example, when this is executed, row 1 will add two new rows underneath of it creating rows 2 and 3. Then after that, for row four, it will have two new rows underneath that creating rows 5 and 6. Hopefully you understand where I am getting at. What I am needing to do is this, currently, this formula only makes two new rows underneath one row, one at one time rather then executing it all at once. This will apply to all rows that have data in them. Can I have some help please with trying to get this to execute at once? I've tried different ways of trying to get this to work but I have not had any luck doing so. Are the any suggestions you could give me?

Comment: What makes you think it is possible to make this "executing it all at once"?

Comment: function fillRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn);
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var rowsToUpdate = [];


  for (var i = 0; i < lastRow; i += 3) {
    if (!isRowEmpty(values[i])) {
      var dataToCopy = values[i];
      for (var j = i + 1; j < i + 3; j++) {
        if (j < lastRow) {
          rowsToUpdate.push({ row: j, data: dataToCopy });
        }
      }
    }
  }

Comment: // Batch update the collected rows
  var updatedValues = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).getValues(); // Get all data again to prepare for batch update
  rowsToUpdate.forEach(function(item) {
    updatedValues[item.row] = item.data;
  });

  // Write all updates back to the sheet in one call
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastColumn).setValues(updatedValues);
}

Comment: Those are the same formula, I could not just add them as the same comment. What makes me think that it can execute at once is because this formula can add data to blank rows all at once when I execute it, showing that it is possible for something like this to happen

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function addTwoBlankRows() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let d = 0;
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const os = vs.reduce((a,r,i) => {
    a.push(r);
    a.push(new Array(r.length).fill(''));
    a.push(new Array(r.length).fill(''));
    return a;
  },[])
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(os));
  sh.clear();
  sh.getRange(1,1,os.length,os[0].length).setValues(os);
}
```

Sheet0: before

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 |
| A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 |
| A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 |
| A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 |
| A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 |
| A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 |
| A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 |
| A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 |
| A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 |

Sheet0: after

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A2 | B2 | C2 | D2 | E2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A5 | B5 | C5 | D5 | E5 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A6 | B6 | C6 | D6 | E6 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A8 | B8 | C8 | D8 | E8 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |
| A10 | B10 | C10 | D10 | E10 |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Optional method:

```
function addNBlankRows(N=2) {//see default parameters
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  let d = 0;
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const os = vs.reduce((a, r, i) => {
    a.push(r);
    [...new Array(N).keys()].forEach(e => a.push(new Array(r.length).fill('')));
    return a;
  }, [])
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(os));
  sh.clear();
  sh.getRange(1, 1, os.length, os[0].length).setValues(os);
}
```

- [Default Parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)